# Is Subaru ever caught in the vault?

Tags: ro-kyu-bu

During episode 6 of *Ro-Kyu-Bu!*, Subaru hides in a gymnastic vault in order to watch the basketball game, since Natsuhi is his substitute coach. Not wanting to be caught, he is unable to escape as the vault is moved into a storage room. Before he leaves, however, the girls come in and start to change, but then notice "something white" in the vault, and go to look.

[image: "Look, there's something white in that vault."]

However, the episode ends here, and episode 7 picks up in a completely different place and makes no mention of this. Was Subaru ever caught? What exactly happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the bottom of Subaru's untucked dress shirt is seen and tugged on, one assumes by the scream that he was discovered.

[image: He should've tucked it in]